# Supabase return invalid json in response Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I m new in Supabase when I try to fetch my table data so the return in response is invalid JSON. how to convert it ?

Supabase calling method code is:

```
try {
  var response = await SupabaseCredentials.supabaseClient
      .from("emp_table")
      .select();
  print("response.data");
  print(response);
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
}
```

}

Returning response is:

```
[{id: 1, created_at: 2023-01-12T10:59:08.631522+00:00, emp_designation: Technical, emp_username: fzn, emp_contact: +91989274, emp_email: m.developer0@gmail.com, emp_address: Uttar Pradesh.}]
```

This response is an invalid JSON

Comment: try to create a model class, check [this example](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-project-Helper/blob/master/jsonFormating/sample1.dart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro just used jsonEncode(YOUR_RESPONSE);
Before converting your object in JSON use import 'dart:convert';

Example:

```
try {
  var response = await SupabaseCredentials.supabaseClient
      .from("emp_table")
      .select();
  print("response.data");
  print(jsonEncode(response));
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
}
```